Site can't be reached in macOS - Robotframework selenium
''' *** Keywords ***
check ztrass url session
    [Arguments]        ${server}
    ${session_id}=     Browsersession       ${server}//  by this local default browser is opened and we copy this url 
    ${url}=            Set Variable         "${session_id}"
    ${url_state}=      Run Keyword And Continue On Failure   check_url     ${url}
    ${sesionURL}=      check_Sessionurl      ${url_state}
    [Return]           ${url}    ${sesionURL}     ${url_state}

Verify to Okta steps
     [Arguments]    ${url}
         ${url_state}=     check_url       ${url}
         log     ${url_state}

         ${Options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
         Call Method    ${Options}   add_argument   --lang\=en
    #    Call Method    ${Options}   add_argument    --headless
         Call Method    ${Options}   add_argument    --ignore-certificate-errors
         Call Method    ${Options}   add_argument    --allow-running-insecure-content
         Create WebDriver    Chrome   options=${Options}
         Set Window Size    1200    720
         maximize browser window
         #Delete All Cookies

         Go To   ${url_state}
         #open browser       ${url_state}     Chrome
         Login to Okta
         sleep  10
         Verify OTP
         
def Browsersession(variable):
    command = 'ssh -F C:/pomerium/config {} -D 8080'.format(variable)
    print(command)
    child = pexpect.run(command, timeout=20)
    print("get_url", child)
    return child

Verify OTP
    [Documentation]         This Keywords is Enter the OKTA authentication OTP
    ${otp}                  Get Authentication Code     ${securityKey}
    Click Element           ${inputLoc}
    input text              ${inputLoc}  ${otp}
    Log    ${otp}
    capture page screenshot
    Wait Until Element Is Visible        ${signINBtn}   ${waitTime}
    Click Element                        ${signINBtn}  # after clicking it will redirect to page with same port that we fetched from  URL and its will show login completed.
    Sleep    5
    capture page screenshot
'''

After verifying a OTP its showing site can't reached because its opening different port.  This is only an issue on macOS ,in windows machine this script is working fine.
In 1st browsing session, default browser is opened when fetching the URL I am using in selenium but after verifying OTP, why is the browser redirected to a different port and showing that site can't be reached.
